# Is there any benefit to use window.open rather than to use <a>?

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen some websites where they use a Javascript function for linking things instead of using  or href. Is there any true benefit to this or is it just a preference thing?

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include an example of the HTML you’ve seen. In general, please see [Which "href" value should I use for JavaScript links, "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?](/a/8525002/4642212), [Anchor or button](/q/18314019/4642212). Read about the semantics and [accessibility concerns](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#accessibility).

Comment: You can programmatically close a window/tab opened by `window.open`.